# Creating an array of variables in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, tabular

I think the reason I can't Google this answer, is because I don't know the terms to use. So apologies if this post frustrates.

What I want to create is an array of multi-part variables; so that a set of keywords can correspond with a corresponding MQTT topic. The background (unrelated to the question) - I intend natural spoken language to be converted into automation triggers; once I have my table, a function can compare the spoken sentence against the array/table I am trying to create, and if the keywords match, the corresponding MQTT message is sent. I would like to use this table/array approach, so that the overall solution is easily updated.

In some imaginary language, the code to build such a table might look like this:

```
declare -a commandarray
{"keywords":"'lounge tv on'","mqtt":"lounge/tv{on}"} >> $commandarray
{"keywords":"'lounge tv off'","mqtt":"lounge/tv{off}"} >> $commandarray
{"keywords":"'bedroom tv on'","mqtt":"bedroom/tv{on}"} >> $commandarray
{"keywords":"'bedroom tv off'","mqtt":"bedroom/tv{off}"} >> $commandarray
```

I guess the result would be a table with column headers of "keywords" and "mqtt", that might display like this. I don't care how it displays, this is just to help explain myself.

```
keywords            mqtt
--------            --------
lounge tv on        lounge/tv{on}       
lounge tv off       lounge/tv{off}       
bedroom tv on       bedroom/tv{on}       
bedroom tv off      bedroom/tv{off}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why does this have to be done in bash? Just pick the scripting language of your choice.

Comment: bash is the most natural fit - this is for home automation and the docker container is stripped quite minimal.

I did actually find that link, but it doesn't really cover what I am after (thanks). I think the term I am looking for is "hash tables" - googling now..

Comment: I am starting to think that I should create a separate csv file.

Comment: The closest bash has to a hash table is an associative array (bash v4 only). But the entries in associative arrays are just text, not any more complex data structures. bash doesn't really *have* data structures, just various ways of storing text strings. If you're trying to do anything even slightly complicated, you should really use almost any language other than bash. Do you have Python? Perl?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Gordon, I thought my google skills were broken! Yes bash makes things more difficult, but in docker containers I strive to keep things as unadulterated as possible.

Comment: @Thilo, please don't link the ABS -- it's the W3Schools of bash, full of examples that showcase bad practices. Over in the freenode #bash channel, we spend half our time helping people unlearn bad habits they picked up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is a bash 4 feature called an *associative array*.

```
declare -A commands=(
  ["lounge tv on"]="lounge/tv{on}"
  ["lounge tv off"]="lounge/tv{off}"
  ["bedroom tv on"]="bedroom/tv{on}"
  ["bedroom tv off"]="bedroom/tv{off}"
)
```

A lookup is something like the following:

```
input="lounge tv on"
echo "Running command: ${commands[$input]}"
```

...and an assignment is akin to:

```
commands["new command"]="new/command{parameter}"
```

Associative arrays are covered in detail in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays), and in [the bash-hackers' wiki page on arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the terminology!

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way was to create a separate file, rather than creating a table.

so this is the contents of commands.txt:

```
lounge tv on;lounge/tv{on}
lounge television on;lounge/tv{on}
lounge tv off;lounge/tv{off}
lounge television off;lounge/tv{off}
```

..and the code to process the file:

```
commandsfile="/config/Scripts/mqtt/commands.txt"
cat $commandsfile | while read command; do
    keywords=$(echo $command | cut -d ";" -f1)
    mqtt=$(echo $command | cut -d ";" -f2)
done
```

Comment: `cat $commandsfile` is much buggier than putting `< "$commandsfile"` at the end of your loop. The `cat` version can't handle filenames with spaces, and it puts the loop in a subshell such that variables it sets aren't available after the loop exits -- this behavior is described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Also, `echo $command | cut -d ";" -f1` is both less efficient and more buggy than just using `while IFS=';' read -r keywords mqtt _; do` in the first place, as described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).